# How to include mime types (JPG, HTML) in Evernote addNote() (API/Python call)?

Tags: python, api, mime, evernote

I've been doing 'proof of concept' by emailing .jpg and .html files AS ATTACHMENTS to my EN (premium) acct.  All goes well -- the "attached" items are displayed in the note.

I've also been trying to do some challenging things with the API (tried Perl but had version problems - now Python).

In particular, I'd like to achieve the same result as with the "attached" emails.  I tried adding Resource to a Note. As in

```
md5 = hashlib.md5()
shlib.md5()
md5.update(image)
hash = md5.digest()
hashHex = binascii.hexlify(hash)

data = Types.Data()
data.size = len(image)
data.bodyHash = hash
data.body = image

resource = Types.Resource()
resource.mime = 'text/html'
resource.data = data

note.resources = [ resource ]
note.created = 1321009871000  #   \____  Kludging in a constant for now.
note.updated = 1321009871000  #   /

note = note_store.createNote(note)
print "Note created: %s" % note.guid
```

...once I figured out the need for MD5, binascii, etc.

A very curious result.  Mostly the "resource" file isn't displayed -- certainly not as an integral part of the note, as before, with email.

BUT in the case of an html instance, searching for a word in the (invisible) HTML file resulted in a correct match.

Any pointers on how to use addNote with various mime types that EN is CAPABLE of understanding (as shown by email experiment, or for that matter, drag-and-drop) would be appreciated.  When I get some working code, I will share it.

Thanks,  Hal

Answer (score 1):

Resource mime types you can use for Evernote to render inline are listed in this [doc](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/resources.php#types).

Answer (score 0):

It seems a resource does nothing unless there is a bit of (ENML) code to anchor it somewhere in the note content.  I.e. insert something like:

```
nBody += "<en-media type=\"%s\" hash=\"%s\" /><br />" % \
       (resource.mime, hashHex)
```

if nBody is variable used to construct the note content.

I think you also use the resource/anchor method for a PDF file, but HTML must be(?) inserted right into the note content which involves some conversion; so far I have the following links to resources from HTML to ENML conversion:

https://github.com/vincentlaucy/enmlOfHtml
        which is discussed with links to other resources here:
 https://kleineblase.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/convert-html-to-enml-for-evernote-a-non-trivial-process/